# SORL Thumbnail Django - 304

Tags: django, caching

I am maintaining a Django site which uses SORL to generate thumbnails for book covers. While searching for performance issues and bandwidth consumption issues, I noticed that asking a thumbnail for a book always serves the file, I never get a 304-Not Modified.

Is there a way (besides serving static files) to cache those images client-side?
I'd like to see a 304 instead of 200 everytime I visit the same pages (and same thumbs).

Tx
Yoeri

Comment: What server are you using? You are still serving static files, just that sorl thumbnail is creating the thumbnails in the background and reporting their location via redis/memcache to the client who finally requests them from the webserver

Comment: Everything is running on an Ubuntu Server using Nginx / gunicorn.